# Do statisticians use the Jeffreys' prior in actual applied work?

Tags: bayesian, prior, jeffreys-prior

When I learned about the Jeffreys' prior in my graduate statistical inference class my professors made it sound sort of like it was interesting mostly for historical reasons rather than because anyone would ever use it. Then when I took Bayesian data analysis, we were never asked to use Jeffreys' priors. Does anyone actually use these in practice. If so (or if not), why or why not? Why do some statisticians not take it seriously?

Comment: I like to use Jeffreys' prior as a default/non-informative prior for the simple binomial model ($p\left(\theta\right)\propto\sqrt{\theta\left(1-\theta\right)}$). It's conjugate with weight equivalent to a single datum and it's a 1$^{\rm{st}}$-order probability-matching prior, so I have a good feeling for what it does to the likelihood function and for how to interpret the resulting credible intervals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A partial answer to this is found in Gelman et al., *Bayesian Data Analysis*, 3rd ed.

> Jeffreys' principle can be extended to multiparameter models, but the results are more controversial. Simpler approaches based on assuming independent noninformative prior distributions for the components of the vector parameter $\theta$ can give different results than are obtained with Jeffreys' principle. When the number of parameters in a problem is large, we find it useful to abandon pure noninformative prior distributions in favor of hierarchical models, as we discuss in Chapter 5.

When Gelman writes that the results are "controversial," I believe he means that a prior that is noninformative in one dimension tends to become strongly informative in several. If memory serves, this was a claim made in the same section of *BDA* 2nd ed., but I don't have a copy with me at the moment.

Comment: Gelman LOVES hierarchical models

Comment: And with very good reason